# sum the result of certain rows by comparing string values of column

Tags: sql, select

I have this table:

```
fy       period       division         employee_id      category_name      amount
2013     4            Sales            123452           Salary             130000
2013     4            Marketing        124232           Salary             120000
2013     4            Sales-WC         124244           Bonus              10000
2013     4            Sales            124244           Adjustments        1000
2013     4            Sales-WC         897287           Salary             65000
```

I'm trying to get a query that will give me the sum of the amounts for each category, but the trick is I want to combine the division when it has '-WC' on it.

This query:

```
select division_name, category_name, SUM(amount) as amount
FROM tblStaff 
where fy=2013 and period=4
group by division_name, category_name
```

Gives me close to what I want:

```
division      category_name        amount
Sales         Salary               130000
Sales-WC      Salary               65000
Sales-WC      Bonus                1000
Marketing     Salary               120000
Sales         Adjustments          1000
```

But What I would like is:

```
division      category_name        amount
Sales         Salary               195000
Sales-WC      Bonus                1000
Marketing     Salary               120000
Sales         Adjustments          1000
```

Where category_name 'Salary' has been combined for 'Sales' and 'Sales-WC'.

I tried starting with a using a case statement like:

```
SELECT case 
   when division_name = division_name + '-WC' THEN division_name
   ELSE 'not found' --did this just for testing
   END as 'division_name',
   category_name,
   SUM(amount)
   FROM tblStaff
   where fy=2013 and period=4
   group by division_name, category_name
```

But it appears I can't use a column name in the part of the case statement like that, because when i run this command I just get division_name = 'not found' for every row.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check if the division_name ends with '-WC' and then strip it off:

```
select
   case 
      when division_name like '%-WC' 
      then substring(division_name from 1 for position('-WC' in division_name) -1) 
      else division_name
   end,
   category_name, SUM(amount) as amount
FROM tblStaff 
where fy=2013 and period_=4
group by 
   case 
      when division_name like '%-WC' 
      then substring(division_name from 1 for position('-WC' in division_name) -1) 
      else division_name
   end,
   category_name
```

Comment: This is basically it, except i had to use the LEFT/LEN functions instead as described in @scraatz solution.  Marking yours as answer since it really did answer the complete question.  Thanks!

Comment: You question was tagged with "SQL" and my answer is 100% Standard SQL :-)

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `LIKE`:

```
SELECT
  case 
    when division_name LIKE '%-WC' THEN replace(division_name, '-WC', '') 
    ELSE division_name
  END as 'division_name',
...
```

or you could just do this:

```
SELECT
  replace(division_name, '-WC', '') as division_name,
  ...
GROUP BY replace(division_name, '-WC', '')
```

Comment: This is great thanks!  This does change the name of the division column correctly, but it doesn't seem to SUM the values, I'm still getting 130000 for Sales, where I'm hoping to get 195000.

Comment: By combining your answer with @scraatz I was able to get the right query.  Thanks!

Comment: @russds try the simple replace

Answer (score 1):

You could create a view that strips the "-WC" from the divisions and than use your first query on that view.

```
CREATE VIEW _table AS
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(division, 3) = '-WC' THEN RIGHT(division, LENGTH(division)-3) ELSE division END AS _division, .... FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT case division_name
WHEN division_name = division_name + '-WC' THEN division_name
ELSE 'not found'
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189074(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I think that's another way of doing the CASE statement, but I tried it, and it doesn't seem to solve my issue.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Does this solve the `division_name = 'not found'` error?

Comment: Maybe I've missed something, but isn't it impossible for `something` to be equal to `something + '-WC'`?

Comment: @Bohemian: No, you haven't missed anything.  That was in his original source.

Comment: Good call @Bohemian, I updated to "division_name *like* division_name + '-WC'", but still don't get the results I'm looking for.   I'm not sure if even using the Case statement would know to SUM the values that I want.

Comment: @russds: I'm not sure guessing is what you want to do here.  There isn't going to be any value for division_name that is *like* division_name + '-WC'